# Simplify es6 snippet forEach

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am trying to find a better way to write this snippet (parse an object) in javascript (es5) using forEach.

```
isCurrentUserIsInSubPeriod(){
    let itemFounded = false
    obj.forEach(data => {
      if (data.check)
        itemFounded = true
    });
    return itemFounded
}
```

Comment: Since there is no `.forEach()` method on an object, please describe what the actual problem is here so we can help you with other/better solutions.  Are you just trying to find out if there is any property on an object itself is an object with a `.check` property?  Or just trying to see if the object itself has a `.check` property?  Questions where you ask about your proposed solution without telling us what the actual overall problem is make it impossible for us to offer answers better than the solution you've already thought of and when your solution is untenable, we can't help at all.

Comment: What does "parse an object " mean?

Comment: "parse an object " means "parse an object ". check all value inside an object

Comment: Are you trying to examine the items in an array or the properties of an object?  Is `obj` an array or a plain object?

Answer (score 5):

You can use [Array.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) instead.

```
isCurrentUserIsInSubPeriod(){
    return obj.some(data => data.check);
}
```

Comment: This seems to assume that `obj` is an array.  Do we actually know that?  The OP says they're trying to "parse an object", whatever the heck that is.

Comment: @jfriend00, yes, that's true. Although many things point to the use of an array because of the use of forEach, and arrays being instances of objects. Maybe that is how the OP understands/explains arrays? I suppose we'll find out soon

Answer (score 0):

If you want to iterate over an object using es5 syntax, you should use a [for-in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop. The `for each` method should only be used with arrays. The most terse way to construct the rest of the statement is with a ternary expression.

```
isCurrentUserIsInSubPeriod(){
  let itemFounded = false;
  for (data in obj) {
    data.checked ? itemFounded =  true : itemFounded = false;
  }
  return itemFounded;
}
```

Comment: `data.checked ? itemFounded =  true : itemFounded = false;` can be simplified to `itemFounded = data.checked;` (which is more terse and easier to understand). Btw, since `obj` is an array, `data` will be the *indexes* of the array (`0`, `1`, etc) and `data.checked` will always be `undefined`. If any, you want `obj[data]`.